# How to set fixed correlation id for DB2 connection in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, db2, odbc

I am new to consuming db2 from a .net application.
My connection string looks like this

```
Server=myAddress:myPortNumber;Database=myDataBase;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword;
```

I am opening the connection and calling a stored procedure with success

```
using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString) )
using (OdbcCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = commandText;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.Add("@KundenEmail", OdbcType.NChar, 50).Value = KundenEmail

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    connection.Open();

    using (OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(command))
    {
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
}
```

I still can't figure out how to set the correlation id(CORRID) to a fixed value.
Is there a way to do this in code or to set it through the parameters in the config file?

Any help would be welcome,
thanks in advance

(Specifically the thread CORRID)

> ```
>                            THREAD DETAIL
> ```
>
> PLAN
>   + Thread:  Plan=KO2PLAN   Connid=DB2CALL  Corrid=D821DM4S     Authid=DB2PM
>   + Attach:  BATCH          JOB Name=D821DM4S                   JOB Asid= 122
>   + Package: DGO@SDOB       Collection=KO2OM410
>
> place a 'T' in front of command to view by tablespace, 'D' by database

iio

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of documentation about it, but it looks like the "ProgramName" parameter of the connection string will set the Correlation ID. If you're using the [`DB2ConnectionStringBuilder`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2ConnectionStringBuilderClass.html) class, you can set it using that class (the property is called "ProgramName" as well).

If you build your Connection String manually, you can add it like so:

```
Database=xxx;User ID=yyy;Password=zzz;ProgramName=YourCorrelationId
```

There is also a property on the [`DB2Connection`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc/doc/DB2ConnectionClass.html) class (`ClientProgramName`) that sets this as well.

In my testing, it seems like you need to set this before you open the connection.